# Papers.js exportJSON (Options) how to specify the Options?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Paper.js, in Javascript, because I need to debug my code.

I want to generate a Json String of my drawings, which works well.
But I need to reduce the precision.
0 is 0.0003. 510.05 = 510.05005..such things.

Documentation mentions:
————

> exportJSON([options])
>
> Exports (serializes) the project with all its layers and child items to a JSON data object or string.
> Options:
> options.asString: Boolean — whether the JSON is returned as a Object or a String — default: true.
> options.precision: Number — the amount of fractional digits in numbers used in JSON data — default: 5.
> Parameters:
> options: Object — the serialization options — optional
> Returns:
> String — the exported JSON data

I do not understand what this means. How specify these options? Whatever I try endup in a crash.

I am programming Javascript since about 3 month, I am coming from C and Assembler languages.
Maybe my question is too simple for this forum?

I did try:

```
json_vect_string = layer_wall_vector.exportJSON(true, 2);
json_vect_string = layer_wall_vector.exportJSON(asString = true, precision = 2);
json_vect_string = layer_wall_vector.exportJSON(options.asString = true, options.precision = 2);
```

Comment: The documentation says "options: Object — the serialization options — optional" so [look up *object* in an introductory js tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

Comment: It means that you need to call it as `json_vect_string = layer_wall_vector.exportJSON(precision: 2)` to have two decimal places. It still doesn't guarantee that the values will be accurate because of floating point arithmetic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems. Common example of that is `0.1 + 0.2 => 0.30000000000000004`

Comment: Thank you so much!

@Quentin: What a shame, sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees.
works perfectly, thank you very much.


exportJSON(precision: 2) does not work, VSCode already complains wrong syntax.

const expjsonOptoins = {
  "asString" : true,
  "precision": 2
}
  let json_vect_string = layer_wall_vector.exportJSON(expjsonOptoins);

works perfectly and is most easily understandable.

Yes the precision with the arithmetics may be a problem, will see when I am ready with my program.